# Sharing array of bins between threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an application that is multithreaded and working OK. However it's hitting lock contention issues (checked by snapshotting the java stack and seeing whats waiting).

Each thread consumes objects off a list and either rejects each or places it into a Bin.

The Bins are initially null as each can be expensive (and there is potentially a **lot** of them).

The code that is causing the contention looks roughly like this:

```
public void addToBin(Bin[] bins, Item item) {
   Bin bin;
   int bin_index = item.bin_index
   synchronized(bins) {
      bin = bins[bin_index];
      if(bin==null) {
        bin = new Bin();
        bins[bin_index] = bin;
      }
   }
   synchronized(bin) {
     bin.add(item);
   }
}
```

It is the synchronization on the `bins` array that is the bottleneck.

It was suggested to me by a colleague to use double checked locking to solve this, but we're unsure exactly what would be involved to make it safe. The suggested solution looks like this:

```
public void addToBin(Bin[] bins, Item item) {
   int bin_index = item.bin_index
   Bin bin = bins[bin_index];

   if(bin==null) {
     synchronized(bins) {
        bin = bins[bin_index];
        if(bin==null) {
          bin = new Bin();
          bins[bin_index] = bin;
        }
     }
   }

   synchronized(bin) {
     bin.add(item);
   }
}
```

Is this safe and/or is there a better/safer/more idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: Why not use a queue feeding one collector thread that manages the bins?

Comment: Also, be more specific about "expensive" and "a lot". Unless we're talking native data structures or reflection and hundreds of thousands, this lazy initialization looks like premature optimization. (Given that your binning is worth the overhead of multithreading, I presume your input data set is large.)

Comment: Millions of bins is not unusual. Data sets can be 10s of terabytes.
Memory usage is 10s-100s GB.

Comment: Why is this all being kept in RAM, then? That sounds like the sort of job where appending to a file per bin would be more effective.

Comment: This is all getting kept in memory because hitting disk is slow. Its already pulling the objects off disk as little as possible, writing intermediate results back to disk will kill performance (far worse than existing lock contention). Once the data is binned and processed final reduced results will go to disk.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As already stated in the answer of Malt, Java already provides many lock-free data structures and concepts that can be used to solve this problem. I'd like to add a more detailed example using `AtomicReferenceArray`:

Assuming, `bins` is an `AtomicReferenceArray`, the following code performs a lock free update in case of a `null` entry:

```
Bin bin = bins.get(index);
while (bin == null) {
    bin = new Bin();
    if (!bins.compareAndSet(index, null, bin)) {
        // some other thread already set the bin in the meantime
        bin = bins.get(index);
    }
}
// use bin as usual
```

Since Java 8, there is a more elegant solution for that:

```
Bin bin = bins.updateAndGet(index, oldBin -> oldBin == null ? new Bin() : oldBin);
// use bin as usual
```

Node: The Java 8 version is - while still non-blocking - perceptibly slower than the Java 7 version above due to the fact that `updateAndGet` will *always* update the array even if the value does not change. This might or might not be negligible depending on the overal costs for the entire bin-update-operation.

---

Another very elegant strategy might be to just pre-fill the entire `bins` array with newly created `Bin` instances, before handing over the array to the worker threads. As the threads then don't have to modify the array, this will reduce the needs for synchronization to the `Bin` objects themselves. Fill the array can be easily done multi-threaded by using `Arrays.parallelSetAll` (since Java 8):

```
Arrays.parallelSetAll(bins, i -> new Bin());
```

**Update 2:** If this is an option depends on the expected output of your algorithm: Will in the end the `bins` array be filled totally, densely or just sparsely? (In the first case, pre-filling is advicable. In the second case, it depends - as so often. In the latter case it's probably a bad idea).

---

**Update 1:** Don't use double-checked-locking! It is not safe! The problem here is visibility, not atomicitiy. In your case, the reading thread might get a partly constructed (hence corrupt) `Bin` instance. For details see http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html.

Comment: From the OP's question: *The Bins are initially null as each can be expensive (and there is potentially a lot of them).*, thus the option of setting them up ahead of time does not seem viable.

Comment: @MatthieuM. You're right. Embarrassingly missed that part. The question is if the bins array will be totally, densely, or just sparsely filled in the end. In the first two cases, using `parallelSetAll` might be still an option.

Comment: @MatthieuM. updated my answer to respect your concerns.

Comment: `updateAndGet` will always behave like an update (i.e. perform a volatile write) even if the value does not change. So it’s not a “very elegant” solution. An elegant solution would be a function like `compareAndSet` taking a `Supplier` but such a function doesn’t exist… Btw. if you know that the reference value will never change from non-`null` to `null` you don’t need the `while` loop. A simple `if` will do.

Comment: Don't feel bad, it's easily missed, and prefilling removes a lot of issues. I was actually hoping you would suggest adding a layer of indirection here: if we had a `Lazy<Bin>` with a `get()` method that lazily instantiates the `Bin` the first time it is called (securely), then you could prefill the array of `Lazy<Bin>` and then avoid locking the array itself.

Comment: @Holger it's elegant in that way that it is a non-blocking one-liner. In fact it is much slower than the Java 7 version I posted. But as constructing the `Bin` is expensive (according to the Question), it will most probably outweight this extra costs by far. You are right concerning the `while`. I had an `if` in the beginning but changed it to `while` as this will make the code more robust in case someone reuses this pattern and does not consider the subtle details.

Comment: I implemented a solution based on this technique, and execution time for the corresponding section of code went from 40 minutes to 15 minutes (was 4.5h before threading), which is fast enough that I can start to worry about any other bottlenecks now. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Java has a variety of excellent **lock-free** concurrent data structures, so there's really no need to use arrays with synchronizations for this type of thing.

[ConcurrentSkipListMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html) is a concurrent, sorted, key-value map.
[ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) is a concurrent unsorted key-value.

You can simply use one of these instead of the array. Just set the map key be the Integer index you already use and you're good to go.

There's also Google's [ConcurrentLinkedHashMap](https://code.google.com/p/concurrentlinkedhashmap/) and Google's [Guava Cache](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained), which are excellent for keeping ordered data, and for removing old entries.

Comment: Not to forget AtomicReferenceArray.

Comment: @isnot2bad I looked at AtomicReferenceArray just before posting the original question. I couldn't see a way to translate the code above into it's available features. But it's likely I'm missing something. If it can be used to solve it - I'd love to see an answer demonstrating how.

Comment: @Malt You're right, is it not as easy as I thought. Too much code to post as a comment. I've added a new answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against the 2nd solution because it accesses the `bins` array outside of a synchronized block therefore it is not guaranteed the changes made by another thread is visible to the code that is reading an element from it unsynchronized.

It is not guaranteed that a concurrently added new `Bin` will be seen therefore it might create a new `Bin` for the same index again and discard a concurrently created and stored one - also forgetting that items might be placed in the discarded one.

Comment: I don't think so. In the second solution, it is checked again if the bin remained null in the synchronized area. So it is guaranteed, only one bin is added.

Comment: At least there is one path of execution that does not synchronize properly on the array, so there might be a subtle, yet overlooked visibility issue that makes it fail. So it's a good advice to advice against double checked locking, especially when there are other far more elegant ways to solve this problem.

Comment: @isnot2bad What execution path? I'm willing to learn and don't see a problematic path.

Comment: @EarlGrey If the bin retrieved from the array is not null, the code path does not enter the block synchronizing on the array, hence the reading thread might not see a fully constructed Bin instance. See http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html for details. It's a visibility issue, not an issue concerning atomicity.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the built in java classes help you, you could just create 8 bins locks, say binsALock to binsFLock.

Then divide bin_index by 8, use the reminder to choose the lock to use.

---

If you choose a larger number that is more than the number of threads you have, and use a lock that is very fast when it is contended, then you may do better than choosing 8.

You may also get better result by reducing the number of threads you use.